# If there are three Zealots, does that mean that if the village doesn't lynch, the Zealots will do three kills that night?

Tags: werewolv.es

"If the village fails to lynch a player during the day, the Zealot will randomly kill someone that night."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each Zealot does their own killing visit, though due to their random nature they may visit someone already targeted, protected, etc.